# decomposing a countable set in disjoint unions

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Suppose $\Omega$ is countable and $X : \Omega \to T $ is a random variable. I know I can write $$ \Omega = \bigcup_j \{ w_j \} $$

since $\Omega = \{w_1,w_2,\ldots \}$ is countable. MY question is why is it possible to partition $\Omega $ as follows ?

$$ \Omega = \bigcup_j \{ w : X(w) = j \} \text{ ?} $$

Comment: I'd use the letter $\omega$ rather than $w$ here. It matches $\Omega$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, every $\omega_j \in \Omega$ has to go somewhere, and since there are only a countable number of $\omega_j \in \Omega$, only a countable number of elements of $T$ get hit.  Think about it like this, we can define $t_j := X(\omega_j)$ for each $j$.  Then we have

$$
\Omega = \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^\infty \{\omega_j\} = \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^\infty \{\omega : X(\omega) = t_j \}
$$

I suspect that your confusion is due in part to the use of $j$ as an element of $T$ as well as an index.